# Django model complex query

Tags: python, django

I have the following django model:

```
class Mappings(models.Model):
    placeFrom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    placeTo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    totalTime = models.TimeField()
```

And here is how the table should look populated:

```
placeFrom       placeTo   totalTime     
new york        london        03:55
london          paris         22:33
london          new york      03: 23
amsterdam       london        82:39
```

The idea is to find all database rows for a mapping that doesn't have direct connection.For example, in this case, new york - paris doesn't have direct connection.So, the table rows returned should be

```
new york        london        03:55
london          paris         22:33
```

Any idea how ?
I started by using `Mappings.objects.filter(placeTo="london")`, to get all rows that represent mapping between 'some place' and the 'london'.So, I know that a row returned is potentially good one for me, if the there is a mapping between 'new york' and 'some place' returned, but don't know how to check that..

Answer (score 2):

This is a graph problem, isn't it? You basically need to build up a graph where the nodes are your places and the edges are your mappings (where edge length = mapping.totalTime), and then apply the relevant graph search algorithm (eg [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) to find the shortest path between the relevant nodes.

I don't think there's any way of doing this without getting all the mappings from the database first and building up the graph, though.

Comment: I don't know much about graphs and didn't have them in mind, it's just a  problem I'm working on to find a intermediary location, between 2 not-direct locations...I'll look into this graph search algorithms, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like where you can build up the routes and easily pull out which locations (or nodes) are not connected. Once this is done you need to follow @DanielRoseman advice and use a graph searching algorithm to fill in the gaps

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node('new york')
G.add_node('london')
G.add_node('paris')
G.add_node('amsterdam')

G.add_edge('new york', 'london', weight=235)
G.add_edge('london', 'paris', weight=1353)
G.add_edge('london', 'new york', weight=203)
G.add_edge('amsterdam', 'london', weight=4959)

print 'All places not linked to new york:'
for location in nx.non_neighbors(G,'new york'):
    print location
```

*n.b. To make it clearer I've not shown the importing of data from the model but you get the idea*

You get the following output

```
All places not linked to new york:
paris
amsterdam
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions, I choosed to start with simple solution, which is far from ideal but it'll help me find a better way.This is what I got right now:

```
querySetToEndLocation = Mappings.objects.filter(placeTo="london")
toEnd = []
toMiddle = []
for row in querySetToEndLocation:
  locationFrom = row.placeFrom
  queryNew = Mappings.objects.filter(placeFrom="new york")
  for rowquery in queryNew:
    if locationFrom == rowquery.placeTo:
       toEnd.append(row)
       toMiddle.append(rowquery)
```